# Grey Caps Loc Notify Image Showing on password field?

Tags: php, html, macos, forms, capslock

I'm having a problem with the small grey caps lock notifiaction image that comes up when you click in a password field and turn on caps lock. Mines showing outside the box about twenty pixels to the right of it. This is causing an obstruction so the user cant see a div layer thats in that position.

Can someone please tell me why mine isnt showing inside the password field and how i can get it inside?

My HTML form has been edited with css to display an image background over the boxes so i imagine its to do with the css.

But i cant find anything related to it. Thanks.

Code:

```
<style>



#main{
        width:440px;
        height:0px;
        margin-top:1px;
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-bottom:0px; 
        position:relative;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #main form{
        width:440px;
        height:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
    }

    #main form .row{
        position:relative;

    }

    #main form .row.error:after,
    #main form .row.success:after{
        content:'';

        position:absolute;
        right: 60px;
        top: 8px;
        width:32px;
        height:32px;
        background:url('../img/icons.png') no-repeat;
        margin-right:50px;
    }

    #main form .row.error:after{
        background-position: 0 -79px;
    }

    #main form input[name=email],
    #main form input[name=password]{

        border:none;
        background:url('http://www.playtimeboys.com/img/form/text-boxes.png') no-repeat top left;
        font:14px 'Segoe UI','Arial',sans-serif;
        color:#888;

        outline:none;

        height: 48px;
        margin-top:22px;
        margin-left:-10px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 50px;
        width: 350px;
    }



    #main form .email input{
        background-position:0 -96px;
    }

    #main form .email input:focus{
        background-position:0 -144px;
    }


    #main form .password input{
        background-position:0 -193px;
    }

    #main form .password input:focus{
        background-position:0 -241px;
    }



    /*----------------------------
        The Submit Button
    -----------------------------*/


    #main form input[type=submit]{

        border: 1px solid #004C9B;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        color: #D3EBFF;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        font: bold 24px Cambria,"Hoefler Text",serif;
        margin-top: -46px;
        margin-left:360px;
        padding-top: 7px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #444444;
        width: 100px;
        height:45px;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:100;

        background-color:#0496DA;

        background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0496DA 0%, #0067CD 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0496DA 0%, #0067CD 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0496DA 0%, #0067CD 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0496DA 0%, #0067CD 100%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0496DA 0%, #0067CD 100%);
    }

    #main form input[type=submit]:hover{

        background-color:#0383d3;

        background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0383d3 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0383d3 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0383d3 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0383d3 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0383d3 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        position:absolute;
        z-index:100;
    }

    #main form input[type=submit]:active{

        background-color:#026fcb;

        background-image: linear-gradient(top, #026fcb 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #026fcb 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #026fcb 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #026fcb 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #026fcb 0%, #004c9b 100%);
        position:absolute;
        z-index:100;
    }



    </style>
        </head>


    /*----------------------------
        The HTML
    -----------------------------*/


        <body>
            <div id="main">


                 <form action="login.php" method="post"  >

                    <div class="row email">
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="row password">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login >"  />
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? I also see no code that should display a caps lock warning. Are you missing some JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe a little more clarity and someone could have answered your question.

Comment: He's talking about the automatic capslock notification that shows up in webkit, at least in Safari on OSX. Normally it shows up discretely at the end of a password textfield; with this styling it's showing up outside the textfield and overflowing into other content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this section:

```
#main form input[name=email],
#main form input[name=password]{
    [...snip...]
    height: 48px;
    margin-top:22px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 50px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

You have the field set too wide; the capslock image normally shows up inside the text field. Also, the height of the content-box is too large, and makes the notifier show up extra large. Try instead:

```
    height: 28px; // height of image - 20px
    margin-top:22px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px; // extra 20px of padding on height
    width: 280px; // proper width of image, so contents don't overflow
```

To understand why this was happening, it helps to remember that even tough you styled over the text filed, it's still in there somewhere; and the actual bounds of the underlying textfield are harder to see once you've applied a style. If you find some formatting of textfields or other form widgets to be acting up, it can help to disable the styles that changed them from the default appearance, such as `border:none;` and see what the system thinks the widget looks like. From there it can be easier to spot where the error is.